# Sever Sent Event IOException causing uncatchable IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, server-sent-events

I have an application where clients receive an SseEmitter,
the SseEmitter will relay jms messages to the client.

There's an issue when the client closes the connection (closing the browser).
An IOException will be thrown causing the following uncatchable exception:

```
2019-01-24 12:33:59.163 ERROR 26516 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter     : Exception while processing an asynchronous request

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling [asyncError()] is not valid for a request with Async state [MUST_DISPATCH]
    at org.apache.coyote.AsyncStateMachine.asyncError(AsyncStateMachine.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:512) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:430) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.setErrorState(AsyncContextImpl.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:241) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
```

Catching the IOException doesn't prevent this exception from being thrown.
I've implemented a work around where the client sends a request to remove his emitter from collection of emitters that will send events.

However in the case of a client/browser crash this exception will still be thrown.

```
   @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000L)
      public void sendEvent()  {
           TextMessage message = null;
           try {
               message = messageBlockingQueue.take();
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           for(SseEmitter sseEmitter:emitterMap.values()) {
               TextMessage finalMessage = message;
                   try {
                       sseEmitter.send(finalMessage.getText());
                   }  catch (IOException e) {
                       sseEmitter.completeWithError(e);
                   } catch (JMSException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
            }
        }
```

endpoint:

```
@CrossOrigin(allowCredentials = "true")
@RequestMapping(value = "/event", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SseEmitter getEvent(HttpServletRequest request){
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if(eventService.getEmitterMap().containsKey(session)){
        System.out.println("existing sub found:"+session.getId());
        return eventService.getEmitterMap().get(session);
    }else{
        final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(84000000000L);
        eventService.register(session,emitter);
        System.out.println("created new sub:"+session.getId());
        return emitter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, this exception can be blamed on a bug in tomcat.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15057

To resolve this issue I've switched from tomcat to jetty.